# Distinguishing sets according to more fine-grained notions than cardinality.

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, set-theory, computability

I'm interested in distinguishing sets according to more fine-grained notions than cardinality. Now I don't know a thing about computability theory, but it seems to me that considering sets up to "computable bijection" is an inherently sensible way to achieve this.

To this end, I was thinking:

1. By an *enumerated set,* let us mean a pair $(X,x)$ such that $X$ is equipped with a bijection to $x : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$.
2. Study the category whose objects are enumerated sets, such that an arrow $f : (X,x) \rightarrow (Y,y)$ is just a function $U(f) : X \rightarrow Y$ with the property that $y^{-1} \circ U(f) \circ x$ is a computable function. Note that we're not requiring the diagram involving $x,y$ and $f$ to commute.

Are people talking about this sort of thing? If so, where can I learn more?

Comment: $U(f)=y\circ x^{-1}$ forces everything in this category to be isomorphic. So it doesn't seem to do much in the way of "distinguishing sets". I think a set likely needs some relatively strong structure (i.e. as a subset of $\Bbb N$) to make sense of the "computability" of a set, but I also know very little about such theory.

Comment: You may like the theory of realisability toposes, especially the part that deals with so-called "modest sets".

Answer (score 3):

For subsets of the natural numbers, and for sets naturally connected with such subsets via indexing, the subject has been studied for a very long time. The Wikipedia article on the [Arithmetical Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) will give a start. There has been particularly fine-grained analysis of r.e. degrees, huge literature.

Answer (score -2):

You may wish to extend your ordering range to the [ordinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), which are in some senses more fine-grained than cardinals.

You may also wish to read about [order-embeddings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-embedding) and the constellation of related ideas that are linked and referenced there.